# lpr printing to Xerox Printer sometimes fails due to Unknown Job Owner

Tags: rhel, printing, lp, lpr

At my work, the system I support (hosted on a RHEL 8.4 server) allows to request to print what's on screen, which produces a text file and calls the lpr command with the printer associated to the user (so, lpr -P [printerName] [fileName]). Printers are preemptively added through the lpadmin command of course, with arguments -E, -x [printerName] and -v socket://[printerID]:9100 (that port being for "raw text" as far as I know).

At the main location where the system is used, the office printer was recently changed to a newer one (a Xerox printer), and although printing from other sources is functional, printing from the system has been problematic. The print jobs make it to the printer, but often get denied - and when they do, the "Job Owner" shows as Unknown. But other times, they don't get denied, and the Job Owner shows as "Remote User".

Here's an example of a denied print :
[image: denied print]

And an example of an allowed print :
[image]

I've asked our company's Xerox expert to take a look at the printer's permissions, but from what he saw, it is set to "Allow All Job Types". I've tried adding argument -U [something] to the lpr command in our printing script, but the behavior didn't seem to change. If you have any insight about what could cause the printer to deny these print jobs, I'm a taker ! Thanks.